# Can knitr cache changes made with with() to an environment?

Tags: r, knitr

It would appear that changes to an `environment` object made with `with()` are not cached:

````
```{r}
foo <- new.env()
```

```{r, cache=TRUE}
with(foo, bar <- 42)
```

```{r}
foo$bar
```
````

This will print 42 the first time it is run, and `NULL` afterwards.

I'm not sure if this is a bug (it could be argued that `with()` is a function called for its side-effects) but I'm experimenting with the idea of collecting all analysis results in a set of `environment`s, and it would be great if this would play nicely with `knitr`' s cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't cache your first code chunk, which means every time you compile this document, the first code chunk is executed. That means every time you get a completely new environment.

Then you cached the second code chunk. The most important thing to know about **knitr**'s caching is that cached chunks are not evaluated the second time you compile the document (unless you made changes to the code chunk). Since this code chunk is not evaluated, `bar` is not assigned in the `foo` environment.

In short:

1. `foo` is always a new environment;
2. `bar` won't be created the second time you compile the document.

That explains why `bar` is `NULL`. To fix the problem, you have to cache the first code chunk. But there is another caveat: due to the use of `with()`, **knitr** will fail to discover that `foo` is modified in the second code chunk, so you must tell **knitr** that the object `foo` should be cached (i.e. saved). The complete solution is:

````
```{r, cache=TRUE}
foo <- new.env()
```

```{r, cache=TRUE, cache.vars='foo'}
with(foo, bar <- 42)
```

```{r}
foo$bar
```
````

Comment: It seems to work even without the `cache=TRUE` of the first chunk. The `cache.vars='foo'` in the second chunk seems to be enough.

Comment: @lindelof Without caching the first code chunk, `foo` from the first chunk will be actually a _different_ environment with the `foo` in the second code chunk: the first `foo` is always a new environment, but the second `foo` could be either from the first chunk (the first time the document is compiled), or loaded from cache (the second time the document is compiled). If you think that is fine, feel free not to cache the first code chunk. I just want you to understand the consequence.